# Is there a way to determine unused functions in Xcode4?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode4

I know that functions can be called dynamically, but is there a way to determine statically which functions (and methods of ObjC objects) are not being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is a sensible thing for someone to have attempted to make such a static analysis tool - it would be very complicated, and you would probably find that it would only find trvial examples of functions that would not be called - e.g. functions you've created in your classes, and you have no calls to them.  All the stuff that interacts with Cocoa ... well the problem is that they 'might' be called in different circumstances.

In any case, what you should really be interested in is runtime code coverage - as this would show you (with a decent suite of tests) what code is actually being used, which would be a smaller subset.

Comment: Agreed. This is a tough problem, especially when you start introducing function pointers, callbacks, and heavy conditional code. Sounds like the halting problem.

Comment: @Luke - agreed, the question is interesting - thinking about it made me realize just how hard this would be.  With the use of selectors and message forwarding too.  Instrumenting code for dynamic coverage - not trivial, but far easier to see how you could do that.

Comment: @iandotkelly: interesting idea, doing it dynamically. small hack that comes to mind: run your code through a profiler for a while, extract all function names, and compare with a TAGS database. That should give you some idea, which functions are called seldom or never at all. This is of course stochastically and by no means 100% accurate, but eliminates checking of lots of functions that are actually called.

Comment: @Arne - hey that's not a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

[objc_cover](https://github.com/nst/objc_cover) will help you spotting potentially unused Objective-C methods.

Comment: That seems to only cover a single file.  Is there one that covers a list of files?

Comment: You don't give it a source file, you give it a compiled binary and it returns a list of *potentially* unused selectors.

Answer (score 0):

add `-Wunused-function` to your list of `WARNING_CFLAGS`.

this also considers functions taken by address as referenced (ideal for normal usage). then compile your program with gcc and clang for optimal coverage.

note that this flag does not cover all cases (e.g. exported functions), and it focuses primarily on functions which have internal linkage. diffing using `strip` and `nm` can help isolate external symbols -- i don't know of a good tool for this exact process.

if you want to locate unused objc methods, you should reword your question.